# customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&) want to have customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&, QTableView)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm stuck on a issue I have and I dont know how to solve it.
The issue is that I want to have the QTableView object that I'm working with to be sent to the next function. In this way I don't need to copy the function for all the tables that I have. I can make a generic function and reuse it. But to do that I need to send the QTableView so that   I can add the row I want to add... Please see how my code looks. The code is how I would like to have it.

```
void InputWindow::on_pushButton_ViewMilestone_clicked()
{

    QTableView *viewMilestone = new QTableView;
    viewMilestone->setModel(sourceMilestonesModel);
    viewMilestone->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    viewMilestone->resizeColumnsToContents();
    viewMilestone->setMinimumWidth(getVerticalSizeOfQTableView(viewMilestone));
    viewMilestone->show();

    connect(viewMilestone, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)),
            this, SLOT(showMenu(const QPoint&)));

}

void InputWindow::showMenu(const QPoint &pos, QTableView *tableView)
{
    QAction *insertRowAction = new QAction(this);
    insertRowAction->setText("Insert new row");

    connect(insertRowAction, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(addNewRow()));

    QMenu *rightClickMenu = new QMenu(this);
    rightClickMenu->addAction(insertRowAction);
    rightClickMenu->popup(tableView->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));

}

void InputWindow::addNewRow(QTableView *qTblView)
{
    QAbstractItemModel *tableModel = qTblView->model();
    int rows = tableModel->rowCount();
    tableModel->insertRow(rows);
}
```

Comment: What prevents you from having `QTableView *viewMilestone` as a class member variable and access it from all functions in the class? Is it really necessary to pass it as function parameter?

Comment: Then I have to build one identical function for all the tables. If I have to change or add something in that function then I will probably miss to change in all the copied functions. Thats why I would like to make it general so I can reuse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSignalMapper.html) could be helpful here. It's designed to link multiple QObjects to a single slot and to provide context as to what was the originating source. It's generally more reliable than MarioBlueSkies sender() mechanism as you're more explicitly controlling what gets registered against the Mapper.

Something like this...

```
QSignalMapper *mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const QObject&)),
        this, SLOT(clicked(const QObject&)));

void InputWindow::on_pushButton_ViewMilestone_clicked()
{

    QTableView *viewMilestone = new QTableView;
    viewMilestone->setModel(sourceMilestonesModel);
    viewMilestone->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    viewMilestone->resizeColumnsToContents();
    viewMilestone->setMinimumWidth(getVerticalSizeOfQTableView(viewMilestone));
    viewMilestone->show();
    connect(viewMilestone, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)),                 signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(viewMilestone, viewMilestone);
}
```

Comment: That works. I also get it working by adding a global TableView and putting the TableView I'm using at the moment as the global. Like this.

activeTableView = viewMilestone

Answer (score 0):

You could use `QObject::sender()` to get the object that emitted the signal in `showMenu()` and then use `qobject_cast<QTableView*>` to cast the returned object into `QTableView`.
(Don't forget to check the result of the cast before accessing it - `qobject_cast` returns 0 if it fails)

see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender